# Combine many (if statements + send emails) into one

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, optimization, google-sheets

I have two products in the inventory at which each one has a min. limit; let's say 100Kg for product 1 and 200Kg for product 2

I have tried the below code in order to send emails once the product quantity is below its min. limit

The code is working just fine but it sends an email for each product in case any met the if statement `if (product1Quantity < product1Limit) {` so that if the both of them do meet the status, we will have two emails like that:

Email 1:

Please check

Product 1 80Kg

Email 2:

Please check

product 2 120Kg

Is there any way to modify the code to combine the two cases into one email like that:

Email:

Please check

Product 1 is 80Kg

Product 2 is 120Kg

And so on if we have 4 products while 3 are below their min. limit and the forth one is not, send one email combining only the first three as mentioned

The point is to save the daily quota as much as we can for future growth in case we added many more products. Thanks in advance

```
var product1 = newRow[6];
var product2 = newRow[18];
var inventory = doc.getSheetByName("Inventory");
var allProducts = inventory.getRange(2, 1, inventory.getLastRow()-1, 1).getValues();

if (allProducts.flat().indexOf(product1) != -1 && product1 != "") {
var product1Quantity = inventory.getRange(allProducts.flat().indexOf(product1)+2, 2).getValue();
var product1Limit = inventory.getRange(allProducts.flat().indexOf(product1)+2, 15).getValue();
if (product1Quantity < product1Limit) {
var list1 = product1.concat(product1Quantity);
// mailApp
MailApp.sendEmail({
to: "email",
subject: "subject",
htmlBody: "Please check<br>" +list1+ "<br>",
});
}
}

if (allProducts.flat().indexOf(product2) != -1 && product2 != "") {
var product2Quantity = inventory.getRange(allProducts.flat().indexOf(product2)+2, 2).getValue();
var product2Limit = inventory.getRange(allProducts.flat().indexOf(product2)+2, 15).getValue();
if (product2Quantity < product2Limit) {
var list2 = product2.concat(product2Quantity);
// mailApp
MailApp.sendEmail({
to: "email",
subject: "subject",
htmlBody: "Please check<br>" +list2+ "<br>",
});
}
}
```

Comment: zip products and quantities, filter items that are below limit and if the filtered result is non-empty, send one email with all details

Comment: Can you show the rest of the script, is this within a for-loop? Please remove sensitive information

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than having the whole task of sending an email for each condition, build the email body then send the email.

```
var arr = [];
if(condition1){
  arr.push('Product 1')
}

if(condition2){
  arr.push('Product 2')
}

if(arr.length > 0) {
  var body = arr.join('\n');
  MailApp.sendEmail(recipient,subject,body);
}
```

Comment: It worked just fine. Thank you so much for the help and support @Rubén